# Make Bicep/ARM deploments honour module resource creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a deployment template which creates a vnet, a subnet and 4 private endpoints to existing resources.

I create the subnet and the endpoints via a couple of modules.

Via the `createSubnet.bicep` module I return the id of the created subnet as an output.

Later on in the script I create the endpoints, passing `subnetId` to it as follows:

```
// Create Infrastructure Private Endpoints
module createInfrastructureEndpoints 'modules/createPrivateEndpoint.bicep' = [for (item, index) in infrastructureItems: {
  name: 'infrastructure-pep-${item.Name}'
  params: {
    deploymentTags: deploymentTags
    endpointName: item.name
    groupId: item.groupId
    location: location
    resourceSuffix: resourceSuffix
    privateLinkServiceId: item.privateLinkServiceId
    subnetId: defaultSubnet.outputs.subnetId
  }
}]
```

However, it seems two of the endpoint creations fail with a `ReferencedResourceNotProvisioned` error associated with the defaultSubnet. I note they are the first two chronologically, however the last modified date is after that of the subnet deployment.

Sorry I can't yet post images

```
[![The failed PEP deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhECR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhECR.png)
```

I've checked the generated ARM template and to me it indicates it's waiting for the `subnet-default` module to finish before it can continue

```
{
      "copy": {
        "name": "createInfrastructureEndpoints",
        "count": "[length(variables('infrastructureItems'))]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "[format('infrastructure-pep-{0}', variables('infrastructureItems')[copyIndex()].Name)]",
      ...
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'subnet-default')]"
      ]
    }
```

How can I get the deployment to wait for the actual completion of the resources created in the module?

I would have expected the creation of the infrastructure private endpoints to wait until the subnet was created.

Comment: could you share your bicep file please ? Also subnet should be created inside the vnet resource rather than seperately other it get deleted and recreaetd everytime

Comment: Hey @Thomas thanks for the response, I went with your approach of adding the subnets as part of the vnet and this removed the race issue that happened. I'm happy to consider that an answer if you want to give it?

Comment: Hi@CM231, so does Thomas's reply help to resolve your issue? If it helps, just a remind of [ accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Sorry about that, this has now been done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine there are some issues when creating the subnet resource outside of the vnet resource. I would advice creating the subnet inside the vnet resource.

Here are few related issues regarding VNET/Subnet creation.

- [Create VNET without destroying all subnets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/2786)
- [resource virtualNetworks with subnets wants to delete the existing subnet](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4653)